# Upvotes on not-so-good questions: a consequence of the Triage Queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, upvotes, triage, question-quality

Lately I've [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7743775) [upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7745271) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7743642) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29667048/908174) that should be closed. This has come to my attention in tags that I follow and, more recently, when I gained access to the Close Queue.

I wonder if the Triage Queue has been the cause of this.

It's clear that when three users agree the question *Looks OK*, the latest will have the option to upvote. The description shown to that user is:

> Thanks! The consensus is: this post **Looks OK**
>   Please remember to **upvote** clear, useful, well-researched questions to encourage their authors and help answerers identify them!

This description is clear and yet, I'm guessing the reviewer upvoted the question. Nevertheless, it seems the bold words **Looks OK ... upvote** are taken into account more than the description of what a good question is.

I'm asking if you feel the same. If so, do you think we can resolve this by highlight the words "**clear, useful, well-researched questions**"?

Remarks:

- I'm very aware the reviewers from the Triage Queue, on these questions, may have missed something and that is really the issue. But I consider upvoting the questions even worse.
- This issue is also valid for questions that are really *Just OK*. Questions that shouldn't (and aren't) closed but aren't exactly well-researched or clear.
- I'm the first to say: Upvote! But we need a baseline on this and that baseline is "this question shows research effort; it is clear and useful".
- I'm really just guessing here because I couldn't find a way to correlate the upvote with the Triage Queue.

Comment: I don't upvote the questions if I think they are *just* okay. I simply disregard the message.

Comment: @mmking I only upvote the question if it matches the "baseline" or if I edit it and then I think it's a good question. I'm not sure if the rest of the reviewers do the same...

Comment: Hmm, that's true, I've seen several humdingers lately that puzzled me greatly for getting upvoted.  Always assumed it was just a sockpuppet/friend doing the voting.  The usual way.  The probable way.

Comment: It *would* be helpful to the newer reviewers to stress that they should only upvote the **clear, useful, well-researched questions**. The first time I saw the message, I almost upvoted the question, despite the fact that I thought the content was terrible.

Comment: I think the best way to resolve this would simply be to remove the upvote button. If people care, they can easily open the question in a new tab and upvote it there. I do however think that many only upvote because there is a button that says so, which is not the behaviour we want to encourage.

Comment: @l4mpi That would surely solve the issue but I think it's premature to suggest that (at least without data to backup this "guessing"). I would say that highlighting what a good question should help to mitigate this issue.

Comment: Maybe it's just the people trying their best for the Vox Populi and Electorate badges? =)

Comment: The first time I saw this message I almost felt like I had to upvote the question and not because the question was **clear, useful, well-researched**. Making it clear what type of question should be upvoted, by highlighting the important criteria, would be a plus.

Comment: @KevinB No, "Looks OK" is orthogonal to whether the question deserves an up- or down-vote. There are only three outcomes: either the question must be closed as soon as possible (only the author is capable of fixing it, if anyone), the question should be substantially edited by an H&I reviewer (the needed information is there, but it's poorly put together in any of numerous ways and is presently hard to answer), or the question *cannot be substantially improved but doesn't need to be closed*. This last case is "Looks OK". Triage lets you downvote questions instead of upvoting them for a reason.

Comment: I think more than the **bold** text, the fact that the upvote button actually _jiggles_ to draw attention to it gives the false hint that if you got this far you _should_ upvote...