# Is this (another) good review audit question?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I've bumped into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715508/how-to-set-the-stream-content-in-phpexcel) in the Low Quality Posts review queue. Turns out this was a review audit and I ended up failing. 
The description that this question has is this (emphasis mine):

> I'm using PHP and PHPExcel to get the image filename from a database and perform the stream reader operation. I set my image by using the `setImageResource` function **but it isn't working as expected**. Here's my code

I can't say I really understood the question, but ultimately I voted to close because it isn't clear what is failing and what the OP expects to happen.

I believe the audit picked up this question based on the 5 upvotes. Am I being too harsh and this is a good question?

On another note, can we have some way to clarify this "audit failed" questions? Should I go to the Tavern chat instead of posting here?

Comment: I close voted and downvoted that question....so, no, it is not you.

Comment: @rene: Dito, and added a comment about the missing parts as well as the audit too.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looks like we reversed that question. It is now closed and it had counter votes to balance the score. It shows how mindless up voting does harm. We should really have a feature request to force up voters leave a comment why on earth they up vote on that kind of questions.

All jokes apart, you did take the right action to bring this to meta. You could also drop in one of the chat rooms, The Tavern is fine (both on SO and MSE) and has regulars around that can either explain why it is a good audit or help by leaving some votes to prevent the question to be used as an audit in cases like you encountered.

Comment: "We should really have a feature request to force up voters leave a comment why on earth they up vote on that kind of questions." This would stop sock puppets dead in their tracks - or at least [reveal them for the world to see](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SchmuckBait). I would totally support it as a serious proposal.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the support but it will also make voting no longer anonymous for all of us and that price is to high for me at this moment....

Comment: What, don't you want your +1 comments? ;)

Comment: Thank you all for letting me know that I'm not crazy :) We've seen some strange upvotes lately and [I believe the Triage queue is a part of this problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290794/908174). As for proposals I would rather see a proposal for a queue to review question and answer audits as long as they don't appear to the users that reviewed them and would also avoid the innumerous posts on meta, like mine.

Comment: laugh if you wish, but we _do_ have that feature request: [Force members to leave comments when they upvote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289607/839601)

Comment: Ah, I totally missed that, @gnat. Upvoted.... (but left no comment)...

Comment: @rene that's P && !P, and I now I can use it to derive anything! bwahahaha